# C# thread locking and using a lock object; what should the correct scope be for the lock object?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

Is there a difference between using a lock object that is declared as a field of a class as opposed to local scope?

For example:  Is there a difference between using `lockObject1` or `lockObject2` in the below example?

```
public class Test()
{
   private Object lockObject1 = new Object();

   public void FooBar()
   {
       lock(lockObject1)
       {
          //Thread safe area 1
       }

       var lockObject2 = new Object();
       lock(lockObject2)
       {
           //Thread safe area 2
       }
   }
}
```

It seems like most examples always seem to glaze over the importance of scoping of the chosen lock object.

Comment: Every time that method is called, a new lockObject2 is created, thus each thread will be locked on their own instance, which means the lock is essentially doing nothing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The local lock object will not really be providing any thread safety since multiple threads running FooBar will each have their own object rather than sharing a single object for locking. (Sadly, I have seen this very thing in code headed toward production before I raised the issue and got it corrected in time.)

Comment: So that means, `lockObject1` would only provide thread safety if the same instance of the `Test` class is used across all threads right?  If a new `Test` class is instantiated in every thread then were back to square one like the local `lockObject2` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Use a non-static to provide thread safety within an instance and a static to provide thread safety between multiple instances.

Answer (score 5):

You should always use a private static member variable if you want to lock *all* instances of an object. Use a non-static private member if you want to lock a *specific* instance.

Never use a publicly visible member, or 'this', as you never know when someone else is going to use it for their own lock, and possibly cause deadlocks.

```
public class Test()
{
   private static Object lockObjectAll = new Object();
   private Object lockObjectInstance = new Object();

   public void FooBar()
   {
       lock (lockObjectAll)
       {
          // Thread safe for all instances
       }

       lock (lockObjectInstance)
       {
          // Thread safe for 'this' instance
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your lockObject2 won't protect anything since, it's not going to be locked anywhere else. Do note that multiple calls to FooBar by different threads will not be protected since it's a new instance each time FooBar is called. Also, do note that lockObject1 isn't much better. It allows locking between calls on the same instance. This is good if it's only member variables being accessed. But if some global resource is being accessed, lockObject1 won't protect fully since each instance of the class has its own instance. As suggested by @Haoest, making lockObject1 static should fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make lockObject1 static and you should be alright.

lockObject2 should also be static field to be effective.

Comment: lockObject1 doesn't necessarily need to be static

Comment: @Rob if the FooBar method was static, then lockObject1 *would* have to be static, right?

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't even compile if the method was static and it tried to access a private member